# Nextjs. Как перенести запрос(с приватным ключом) к серверу из react-компонента в api?

Tags: javascript, nextjs

`Next.js приложение => главная страница app/page.jsx => хук useEffect()`

В хуке useEffect выполняю запрос к сервису Infura чтобы создать инстанс провайдера и сохранить его в useRef-е:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const infuraId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INFURA_ID;
    provider.current = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${infuraId}`);
}, []);
```

И всё работает, но меня немного напрягает, что INFURA_ID видно в http-запросе (в url-е).
Не знаю насколько это критично, но я подумал было бы неплохо убрать этот запрос в next-api.
Поэтому я вынес этот запрос в отдельный роут(`app/api/provider/route.js`):

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const INFURA_ID = process.env.INFURA_ID;

export async function GET() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_ID}`);
  const response = { provider };

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(response), { headers });
}
```

А на главной странице(app/page.jsx) в useEffect-е уже обращаюсь к этому api:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProvider = async () => {
      provider.current = await fetch('/api/provider').then(response => response.json());
    }
    
    getProvider();
  }, []);
```

Теперь когда главная страница загружается INFURA_ID уже не палится, а выполняется запрос по адресу http://localhost:3000/api/provider

Но проблема в том, что провайдер, который я получил с помощью своего api какой-то урезанный, в нём к примеру нет метода `getBalance() (provider.getBalance === undefined)`
Я начал кошмарить ChatGPT по этому поводу. И в ходе беседы с ним пришли к выводу, что для того чтобы у меня был этот метод мне нужен не просто provider, а конкретно инстанс ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(). А инстанс класса я так понял через api не протащить, по крайней мере ChatGPT говорит, что это не возможно. У меня же есть некоторые сомнения на этот счёт, возможно удастся с помощью [class-transformer-a](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#readme) решить этот вопрос.

Надеюсь мне удалось достаточно внятно описать проблематику вопроса. Что можно сделать в данной ситуации? Просто я только-только начал изучать Next.js и не до конца разобрался как работать с api в Next.js.